# Yii framework CHtml::link error jump to a named anchor in another page

Tags: character-encoding, hyperlink, yii, anchor, url-encoding

I'm use Yii Framework.

I have a named anchor `<a name="projet">projet</a>` in about.php page.
I've created a link in the index page to the named anchor in the about page like that :

```
     <?php  echo CHtml::link('MyLink',array('site/page','view'=>'about#projet')); ?>
```

But when I click on the link "MyLink", I have an error 404 response with this message :

```
     The requested view "about#projet" was not found.
```

And in the url I have:

```
     localhost/myApps/index.php?r=site/page&view=about%23projet
```

I checked default charset application is UTF-8. So I don't understand why my link isn't well encoded.
Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
echo CHtml::link('MyLink',array('site/page','view'=>'about', '#'=>'projet'));
```